# Plot multiple (all) solutions of Solve as function of parameter

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I have a nonlinear equation that may have different number of solutions, dependant on parameters.

```
f[wc_, g_, U_, k_] := 
 Solve[-I wc x - I g (Conjugate[x]) - (I U + k)/2 Abs[x]^2 x == 0, x]
```

I would like to plot all solutions, as function of one parameter say,

```
Plot[Evaluate[Re[x /. f[1, y, 2, 1]]], {y, 0.0001, 2}]
```

However, I get an empty plot. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When I run your code I get `Greater::nord: Invalid comparison with <complex number> attempted.` which indicates that the `Condition`s for the existence of the solutions given by `Solve` cannot be satisfied for the parameters you have chosen. I tried to show this but unfortunately `Refine` is not too refined. FWIW: `(Re[x] /. f[1, y, 2, 1])[[1]] /. ConditionalExpression[_, cond_] :> Refine[cond, 0.0001 < y < 2]` gives `0 > Sqrt[1 - y^2] && y < 1` which is clearly `False`.

Comment: @Natas, Zero is obviously a valid solution always. Simply printing f[1,2, 2, 1] finds the correct solutions. It is the plotting which does not work

Comment: Indeed. I was too confused by all the `ConditionalExpression`s.

Answer (score 1):

Here we assuming that  g is a real parameter, and write the complex number x as `u+I*v`.
we separated the real part and imaginary part.
we also set g>0

```
  Clear["`*"];
ComplexExpand[-I wc x - 
    I g (Conjugate[x]) - (I U + k)/2 Abs[x]^2 x /. {wc -> 1, U -> 2, 
    k -> 1, x -> u + I*v}];
reg = ImplicitRegion[
   v - u^3/2 + v - g v + u^2 v - (u v^2)/2 + v^3 == 
     0 && -u - g u - u^3 - (u^2 v)/2 - u v^2 - v^3/2 == 0, {g, v, u}];
Resolve[Exists[v, Element[{g, v, u}, reg]] && g > 0, Reals]
```

the result is

```
   (*(0 < g <= 2 && 
   u == 0) || (g > 
    2 && (u == 
      Root[32 - 16 g - 24 g^2 + 20 g^3 - 
         4 g^4 + (56 - 132 g + 80 g^3) #1^2 + (25 - 100 g + 
            100 g^2) #1^4 &, 1] || u == 0 || 
     u == Root[
       32 - 16 g - 24 g^2 + 20 g^3 - 
         4 g^4 + (56 - 132 g + 80 g^3) #1^2 + (25 - 100 g + 
            100 g^2) #1^4 &, 2]))*)
```

It seems that only the root u=0 if 0<g<=2

at the same time we also use `ContourPlot3D` to display the result.

```
 ContourPlot3D[{v - u^3/2 + v - g v + u^2 v - (u v^2)/2 + v^3 == 
   0, -u - g u - u^3 - (u^2 v)/2 - u v^2 - v^3/2 == 0}, {g, -5, 
  5}, {v, -5, 5}, {u, -5, 5}, Mesh -> False, PlotPoints -> 50, 
 ViewProjection -> "Orthographic", AxesLabel -> {g, v, u}, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", 20, Blue}]
```

[image]

```
    ContourPlot3D[{-u - g u - u^3 - (u^2 v)/2 - u v^2 - v^3/2 == 
   0}, {g, -10, 10}, {v, -10, 10}, {u, -10, 10}, 
 MeshFunctions -> 
  Function[{g, v, u}, v - u^3/2 + v - g v + u^2 v - (u v^2)/2 + v^3], 
 Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> Red, 
 ContourStyle -> {Cyan, Opacity[0.1]}, AxesLabel -> {g, v, u}, 
 PlotPoints -> 50, Boxed -> True, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", 20, Blue}, 
 ViewProjection -> "Orthographic"]
```

[image]

We can also plot the 2D graph with g and u

```
       ContourPlot3D[{-u - g u - u^3 - (u^2 v)/2 - u v^2 - v^3/2 == 
    0}, {g, -10, 10}, {v, -10, 10}, {u, -10, 10}, 
  MeshFunctions -> 
   Function[{g, v, u}, v - u^3/2 + v - g v + u^2 v - (u v^2)/2 + v^3],
   Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> {Thick, Red}, ContourStyle -> None, 
  AxesLabel -> {g, v, u}, PlotPoints -> 50, Boxed -> True, 
  LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", 20, Blue}, 
  ViewProjection -> "Orthographic", ViewPoint -> {0, -20, 0}, 
  BoundaryStyle -> None] /. {Graphics3D -> 
   Graphics, {g_, v_, u_} -> {g, u}}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Mathematica has trouble with the `ConditionalExpression` returned by `Solve` for arbitrary arguments.
This is caused by you calling `Evaluate`.
However the problem is that there are a different number of roots for different parameter values.

As you noted in the comments, evaluating the function for numerical arguments does not pose a problem. One solution therefore is to sample the data yourself and then use `ListLinePlot`.

An inelegant way is as follows:

```
data = Module[{fVal, yVal},
   {fVal, yVal} = Reap[
     Table[
      Sow[y]; (Re[x] /. f[1, y, 2, 1]), {y, 10^-4, 2, 1/10}
      ]
     ];
   Transpose[yVal~Join~{#}] & /@ 
    Transpose@(ArrayReshape[#, Max@(Length /@ fVal)] & /@ fVal)
   ];
ListLinePlot[data]
```

[image: Result of the above code]

As pointed out above one problem is that there will be a different number of roots. In this case you can figure out that there will be three branches. Then you could also do

```
myF[wc_, g_, U_, k_] := ArrayReshape[x /. f[wc, g, U, k], {3}]
Plot[Re[myF[1, y, 2, 1]], {y, 10^-4, 2}]
```

[image: Result of the alternative code using Plot]

Clearly the downside is the lack of nice colors.

Answer (score 0):

This approach gives all solution-branches in one step:

```
rex = Simplify[Re[x /. f[1, y, 2, 1]], Im[y] == 0] // Normal;
(*up to 8 solutions*)

Plot[ rex , {y, 0.0001, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: I am not convinced that you are allowed to get rid of `ConditionalExpression`.

Comment: I only assumed `real y`

Comment: But shouldn't `Simplify` take care of that? For instance, `Simplify[ConditionalExpression[x, Im[x] == 0], Im[x] == 0]`.

Comment: I assumed `Simplify[..., Im[y] == 0]` to be  short form of `Simplify[..., Assumptions->Im[y] == 0]`

Comment: Ulrich, you are correct about the short form. My point is that you by issuing `Normal` you are removing conditions. My example was meant to illustrate that `Simplify` can remove conditions if they are satisfied by the assumptions.

Comment: @Natas Sorry I didn't get it. It seems that my solution includes all of your solutions.

Comment: Sure, but for instance `With[{y=1/2}, Re[x /. f[1, y, 2, 1]]]` gives `{0}` which leads me to believe that for `y = 1/2` there is only one solution and not multiple as in your plot. Unfortunately I can't think of any easy example which illustrates the problem better.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I got it!